# Use AJAX to Filtering Data on the Table with Select Box in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have an issue when using AJAX to filter data on the table. I have a select box and table on the page. I want to filter data on the table using the select box. example, if the user chooses value 'Ganjil' on the select box then table just show row that has data 'Ganjil'.

#### AJAX Script:

```
<script>
var semester = $("#inputJenis").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'<?php echo base_url("search/filter") ?>',
        data:"key="+semester,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            $("#tableData").html(data);
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest){
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

#### Controller:

```
public function filter()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $key = $this->input->post('semester');

    if ( $key == 'Ganjil' ) {
        $this->load->model('filter_model');
        $data = $this->filter_model->getGanjil($key);
    } else {
        $this->load->model('filter_model');
        $data = $this->filter_model->getGenap($key);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

#### Model:

```
public function getGanjil($key)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tahunajaran WHERE jenis = '$key'";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $data->result_array();   
}

public function getGenap($key)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tahunajaran WHERE jenis = '$key'";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $data->result_array();   
}
```

When I choose the value of select box table show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**1st Solution** : use        `$key = $this->input->post('key');`  in controller as you access key value pair. So in AJAX call $key is Key. You cant access javascript variable semester like  `$this->input->post('semester');` in your code.

**2nd Solution** :

in ajax call `url:'<?php echo base_url("search/filter/key/") ?>'+semester`

Use $key='' as parameter in controller method .

`public function filter($key='')` as there is no $key accessible in your controller method. You should be accessing in your controller as a parameter. So you can use it in model . In your case there is no $key coming as a parameter in controller.

Also  in your code use

```
$key = $this->input->post($key); as we access $key thru parameter.
```

**-------------Update 1----------**

As per your requirement , AJAX call

```
<script>
      var semester = $("#inputJenis").change(function(){
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:url:'<?php echo base_url("search/filter/key/") ?>'+semester,
          data:"key="+semester,
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(data){
            $("#tableData").html(data);
          },
          error:function(XMLHttpRequest){
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```

And your controller should be like this ->

```
public function filter($key = '')
 {
    $this->load->helper('url');

    if ( $key == 'Ganjil' ) {
        $this->load->model('filter_model');
        $data = $this->filter_model->getGanjil($key);
    } else {
        $this->load->model('filter_model');
        $data = $this->filter_model->getGenap($key);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean about "AJAX call $key is key" sir ? am i just edit my controller or with ajax in script ? thanks

Comment: Hello ,      Do you know in ajax we use Key => Value pair  like `name=>Pratik` . Here name is Key and Pratik is Value. In your case Key is $key and value is semester , getting ? ?  Like $key=>semester . Here semester is Value.

Comment: @AdiSatria Updated , check for `Update1`

Comment: @AdiSatria `Nothing is happen means what?` What error you get ? Is ajax call going well ? Is response going well ? What is URL for post request in Console panel ???

Comment: What I asked was :  Is ajax call going well ? Is response going well ? What is URL for post request in Console panel ??

Comment: Show error whit this message "the URI you submitted has disallowed charachters." What's wrong sir ?

Comment: Take screenshot of it , update your Question . Also include screenshot of Network panel in Firebug.

Comment: i can't do that because i just have 6 reputation. min 10 reputation to upload image...
oh god, i confused how to fix this problem

Comment: @AdiSatria , You are a developer :) So try to find your way out of Hell :)  . Go here http://postimage.org/, upload your images and paste URL in the comments :)

Comment: hey sir, i fixed the error. But now i have new issue, when i choose value on the select box data on the table all disappear. any idea ?

Comment: @AdiSatria There is No Javascript code in your question .And the question is solved .Please ask another question with Javascript code , HTML code in it thanks.